# Workflow Error : The workflow instance exceeded the CPU usage limit of throttle of 00:00:01.2000000

Tags: sharepoint-online, designer-workflow

We are using SharePoint 2013 Designer workflow on SharePoint Online site.

Currently my workflow gets suspended, showing error

> The workflow instance exceeded the CPU usage limit of throttle of 00:00:01.2000000 and could not be unloaded because it was not persistable

Workflow stops while updating multiple fields in one update action.

Answer (score 1):

Check for workflow variables or updateLisItem actions if are in correct format.

Answer (score 0):

I think a reason for this error is updating multiple items in one action. You can put the pause in between or re-write the logic to update 1 item at a time.

This error can be due to endless loops, updating multiple items in one action or creating multiple items in one action and so far.

Comment: Actually some times it works and some time show errors while updating multiple items..